# Crear métodos y funciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, método

Estoy transcribiendo un código que está hecho en MATLAB a Python, y quiero saber cómo debo crear correctamente las funciones de abajo pero en Python.

Función 1:

```
function init=initial(x)
init=0.09 * exp(-x.ˆ2/50);
```

Función 2:

```
function fl=flux(rho)
vf = 15;
rhomax = 0.2;
fl = vf*(1-rho/rhomax).*rho;
```

Leyendo la documentación sobre métedos en Python, hice lo siguiente:

```
def initial (x):
    init=0.09*math.exp(-x**2/50);
return init

def flux(rho):
    vf=15;
    rhomax=0.2;
    fl=vf*(1-rho/rhomax)*rho;
return fl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo es correcto, la estructura general de un script en python seria similar a esto:

```
from math import exp

def initial (x):
    init= 0.09 * exp(-x**2/50);
    print init

def flux(rho):
    vf=15;
    rhom=0.2;
    rhomax = .5 # dfinir valor de rhomax
    fl=vf*(1-rho/rhomax)*rho;
    print fl

def main():
    valor_de_x = 1
    valor_de_rho = 2
    initial(valor_de_x)
    flux(valor_de_rho)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

En tu codigo no hay un valor para rhomax, y para el exp debes de usar las funciones de la librería math de python

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

También puedes revisar PEP8 (PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code)

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/